# Right to get a copy of information held on one by private company in Australia

Tags: privacy, australia

Does anyone know what the law in Australia is with respect of getting copies of information held by Australian companies about oneself - particularly notes made by phone operators and recorded phone calls?

Does it make any difference if I made the call from inside or outside the country to an Australian business ?

(I've run into issues with an Australian Airline incorporated in Queensland)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Australian Privacy Principles require APP Entities who are in possession of information about an individual to give access to that information to that individual upon request by that individual.

Most government departments are APP Entities, but there are other private entities which are APP Entities, including health insurers and other large organizations.

You can contact the Queensland Office of the Information Commissioner (https://www.oic.qld.gov.au/) to ask whether a particular airline is an APP Entity, and for further information.

Comment: Thank you for this pointer - based on it I found https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2018C00034 which means that most companies are required to provide disclosure under Schedule 1, Part 5 of the act in most situations.   I have no doubt that the airline I'm dealing with - whos turnover is way, way greater then $3M/year is an agency.